# OBD2 How can I check that ignition is turned off

Tags: android, obd-ii

I've connected to OBDKey and obtained data. I want immediately close my program when the vehicle is powered down(ignition turned off) How can I check that ignition is turned off?

Answer (score 5):

What about using the RPM value from the engine controller to determine that the engine has stopped running? With OBDKey, use the `010C\r` command. this will be `41 0C 00 00` if the engine is not running or `NO DATA` if the ECU has already shut down.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `ELM327`chipset, you can use the `ATIGN` command which will response `ON` or `OFF`.

In practice, I'm not sure whether this command is actually useful. For socket-powered OBD2 devices, it looks like they always report `ON` when they are powered. See also [ELM327 ATIGN always returns 'ON'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218400/elm327-atign-always-returns-on).